# Laravel 4 migration: class not found exception

Tags: php, migration, laravel, laravel-4

So apparently now I get this weird error when I want to migrate my database

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class '' not found","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\l4crm\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator.php","line":301}}[Finished in 1.3s]
```

Everything used to work of course and it doesn't matter which files I try to migrate (I tried only migrating one table, then another, they all give the same error)

Any ideas? I have been staring myself blind at this for over an hour now.

Also "composer dump-autoload" does not do the trick.

My composer.json autoloads the migrations also.

Comment: Try deleting your `bootstrap/compiled.php` file and test your app. then you can run `php artisan optimize` to create it again.

Comment: I don't appear to have this file. Only files I have under /bootstrap are autoload.php, paths.php and start.php

Comment: Class ' ' not found is weird. Somehow a migration if an empty string class name is getting passed to the migrator. Any non-class files present in the migrations directory?

Comment: just the .gitignore which has always been there. I tried removing it just in case and got the same error still

I even tried removing all my migrations and leave only the users migration (and tried the same with other migrations) and this still doesn't solve the error.

If I don't find the answer I may just create a new project later on and move all the files to the new project and see what happens. I have absolutely no idea where it went wrong though and all my files look good as far as I can tell

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I appear to have solved the problem.

For easiness sake to determine the order of migrations I had renamed the migration files to something like

```
1_create_users_table.php
2_create_..._table.php
3_create_..._table.php
```

and so on. Apparently this gave me the error, it really had to stay in the "**yyyy_mm_dd_hhmmss_create_xxx_table.php**" format.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, I searched the internet and I found this solution that you should update your auto-generated classmap (aka autoload) with this composer command:

```
php composer.phar update
```

or

```
composer update
```

check this link : [I found the solution here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/56)

Answer (score 3):

if `composer dump-autoload` doesn't work, check your class name in the migration file. The className should be the same than the file name without the date

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, this was exactly my issue.  Thanks!  I overlooked this one somehow.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

For me, `composer update` doesn't work (in other situations as well) with Windows for weird reasons.

But,

```
composer dump-autoload
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had deleted a migration in source files but i didn't on "migrations" table on the database.

Delete the row and refresh migrations and do a "composer dump-autoload -o"