# Laravel Seeding error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to seed some info on my oneway table but evertime I run php artisan db:seed, an error would occur

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","me
ssage":"Class 'Oneway' not found","file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\airlines\\app\\database
\\seeds\\OnewayTableSeeder.php","line":8}}
```

I have tried composer dump-autoload but still nothing happens. What seems to be the problem here? 
Is it on my composer or my codes.

OnewayTableSeeder.php

```
 <?php

class OnewayTableSeeder extends Seeder{
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('oneway')->delete();

        Oneway::create(
        array(
            'destination-from'=>'Bacolod',
            'destination-to'=>'Cebu',
            'departure'=> \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate(2014,10,01)->toDateTimeString(), 
        ));

        Oneway::create(
        array(
            'destination-from'=>'Tawi-Tawi',
            'destination-to'=>'Cebu',
            'departure'=> \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate(2014,10,03)->toDateTimeString(), 
        ));

        Oneway::create(
        array(
            'destination-from'=>'Cebu',
            'destination-to'=>'Dipolog',
            'departure'=> \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate(2014,10,16)->toDateTimeString(), 
        ));
    }

}
```

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
    <?php

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Eloquent::unguard();

        // $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
         $this->call('OnewayTableSeeder');
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the name of the file OnewayTableSeeder.php?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply sir. Yes, that is the name of the file.

Comment: have you created a model for your oneway table...if not create one then try again

Comment: No, i didn't create a model. Is it necessary to make a model for seeding?

Comment: I think yes. Because of the static method call you are making in your seed file OneWay::create(). You cannot make that kind of call if you don't have OneWay model class.

Comment: If you do not have a `Oneway` model, then what exactly are you creating with `Oneway::create`?

Comment: Oh now I see Sir @Rohan. I have created now my model and it all works well. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is someone else who had a similar problem with migrations.

[Laravel 4 migration: class not found exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551002/laravel-4-migration-class-not-found-exception)

This might just work for you.

Other than this, make sure you have a model for OneWay and also make sure that the seeder file is named exactly OnewayTableSeeder.php. Moreover try using this package [fzaninotto/Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker)
 to seed your database. I know that the library isn't relevant to the question you asked but it comes in very handy.

Also I personally tried removing either the model or the seeder file and it gives me a different exception than yours. All I can find everywhere is that the seeder file was not included and you should run `composer dump-autoload` or `composer dumpautoload`. Try both of them just for the sake of it.